# Output Type in Factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory

I have 2 classes - `ModelBuilders`: each of it implements an interface with almost the same method:

```
public interface ICanBuildLocalListingsFacebookModel
{
    Task<LocalListingsFacebookModel> BuildAsync(Guid userId, int folderId, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate,
        Guid? companyId);
}

 public interface ICanBuildLocalListingsGoogleMyBusinessModel
    {
        Task<LocalListingsGoogleMyBusinessModel> BuildAsync(Guid userId, int folderId, DateTime? startDate,
            DateTime? endDate, Guid? companyId);
    }
```

As you can see, `BuildAsync` are almost the same except output type.

I have `Factory` to detect what `ModelBuilder` to call:

```
public class InsightsModelFactory : FactoryBase
{
    private readonly IDbSessionManager dbSessionManager;
    public InsightsModelFactory(IDbSessionManager dbSessionManager)
    {
        this.dbSessionManager = dbSessionManager;
    }

    public override dynamic Create(LocalListingEngagement? type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case LocalListingEngagement.Facebook:
                return new LocalListingsFacebookModelBuilder(dbSessionManager);
            case LocalListingEngagement.GoogleMyBusiness:
                return new LocalListingsGoogleMyBusinessModelBuilder(dbSessionManager);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class FactoryBase
{
    public abstract dynamic Create(LocalListingEngagement? type);
}
```

Currently, in the Factory, I have a method `Create` which returns `dynamic` object.

It's because I can't create some common type for 2 interfaces.

Is there any good solution?

---

I'm thinking about creating some common interface which will return `Task<object>` and in specific interfaces just hide that method with keyword `new`, but don't think it's a good solution.

```
public interface ICanBuildLocalListingsGoogleMyBusinessModel: ICanBuildLocalListingsModel
{
    new Task<LocalListingsGoogleMyBusinessModel> BuildAsync(Guid userId, int folderId, DateTime? startDate,
        DateTime? endDate, Guid? companyId);
}

public interface ICanBuildLocalListingsModel
{
    Task<object> BuildAsync(Guid userId, int folderId, DateTime? startDate,
        DateTime? endDate, Guid? companyId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a common model base. Could be interface or abstract base class

```
abstract class ModelBase {
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public Guid MyProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

Common interface can build the common model

```
public interface IModelBuilder{
    Task<BaseModel> BuildAsync(Guid userId, int folderId, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate,
        Guid? companyId);
}
```

Derived interfaces can build off of that making sure that their returned model is derived form the base model.

Factory would return the common interface

```
public abstract class FactoryBase {
    public abstract IModelBuilder Create(LocalListingEngagement type);
}
```

Implementation can use a store to hold the available types and how to initialize the implementations.

```
public class InsightsModelFactory : FactoryBase {

    private readonly IDictionary<LocalListingEngagement, Func<IDbSessionManager, IModelBuilder>> strategies;
    private readonly IDbSessionManager dbSessionManager;

    public InsightsModelFactory(IDbSessionManager dbSessionManager) {
        this.dbSessionManager = dbSessionManager;
        strategies = new Dictionary<LocalListingEngagement, Func<IDbSessionManager, IModelBuilder>>();
        //...populate available builders or create an abstraction that can be injected.
    }

    public override IModelBuilder Create(LocalListingEngagement type) {
        Func<IDbSessionManager, IModelBuilder> stratergy;
        if (strategies.TryGetValue(type, out stratergy)) {
            return stratergy(dbSessionManager);                    
        } else {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that. One thing that I don't know how in Factory method `Create` return this common generic interface...